# Stay/Collapse nav bar

Tags: html, css

I have navbar menus with submenu dropped-down. whenever the menu is clicked then the submenus is expanded however when the submenu is clicked then the sub-menus returns collapsed. How to make the menu and its submenus stay expanded until the other menu is clicked?

[image: wont stay expanded]

above picture, when picture submenu under profile menu is clicked it opens a page and the profile menu stays expanded, until other menu (eg. messages menu) is clicked then profile menu is collapsed.

[`my fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/xmbohx/0L8ag9t3/4/)

Please advise.

Comment: Do the menus have any postion attributes in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you are binding to a css :target that is RESET when any other link is clicked.
Whether this problem is solved, I do not know. But such tasks are usually done using javaScript

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-btn');

let activeNav = null;

links.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const wrapper = item.closest('.item');
    if (!wrapper) {
      return;
    }

    /** 1. START - each menu item is separate*/
    // wrapper.classList.toggle('open');
    /** 1. END - each menu item is separate*/

    /** 2. START - only one active (need variable - activeNav) */
    if (activeNav === wrapper) {
      /** If you want the active to be always, remove this code */
      wrapper.classList.remove('open')
      activeNav = null;
    } else {
      if (activeNav) {
        activeNav.classList.remove('open');
      }
      wrapper.classList.add('open');
      activeNav = wrapper;
    }
    /** 2. START - only one active */
  })
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap');

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
    width: 100%;
    background: #e5e7eb;
    position: relative;
}

.wrapper .header {
    z-index: 1;
    background: #22242A;
    position: fixed;
    /*aslinya width: calc(100%-0%)*/
    width: calc(100%);
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    top: 0;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu {
    width: calc(100%-0%);
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .title {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 900;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .title span {
    color: #4ccee8;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .sidebar-btn {
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 240px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 900;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: color;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu .sidebar-btn:hover {
    color: #4ccee8;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu ul {
    display: flex;
}

/*tombol sebelah my panel*/
.wrapper .header .header-menu ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    color: #000;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: background, color;
}

.wrapper .header .header-menu ul li a:hover {
    background: #4ccee8;
    color: #fff;

}

.wrapper .sidebar {
    z-index: 1;
    background: #2f323a;
    position: fixed;
    top: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    /*begron abu2. aslinya: height: calc(100%-9%);*/
    height: calc(100%);
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: width;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu {
    overflow: hidden;

}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .profile img {
    margin: 20px 0;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .profile p {
    color: #bbb;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    padding: 25px 20px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: color;

}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn:hover {
    color: #4ccee8;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn i {
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .menu-btn .drop-down {
    float: right;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu {
    background: #3498d8;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: background, max-height;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu a {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8fc5e9;
    transition: 0.3s;
    transition-property: background;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu a:hover {
    background: #55b1f0;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item .sub-menu i {
    padding: right 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item.open .sub-menu {
    max-height: 500px;
}

.wrapper .sidebar .sidebar-menu .item:target .sub-menu {
    /* max-height: 500px; */
}

.wrapper .main-container {
    width: (100%-250px);
    margin-top: 70px;
    margin-left: 250px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: url("images/background.jpg")no-repeat;
    height: 100vh;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Apanel</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="header-menu">
                <div class="title">This <span>is</span></div>
                <div class="sidebar-btn">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bell"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-power-off"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-menu">

                <li class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-desktop"></i><span>Dashboard</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="item" id="profile">
                    <a href="#profile" class="menu-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i><span>Profile <i class="fas fa-chevron-down drop-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-image"></i><span>Picture</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-address-card"></i><span>Info</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item" id="messages">
                    <a href="#messages" class="menu-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span> Messages<i class="fas fa-chevron-down drop-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i><span>New</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-envelope-square"></i><span>Sent</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>Spam</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>                                       
                <li class="item" id="settings">
                    <a href="#settings" class="menu-btn">
                        <i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings<i class="fas fa-chevron-down drop-down"></i>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="sub-menu">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i><span>Password</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-language"></i><span>Language</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i><span>Spam</span></a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu-btn">
                        <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i><span>About</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-container">
          <a href="#">link</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```